# I would like my application to overlap the dock (with the app behind of course)

Tags: dock

I'm on 10.7.3.  I have my dock at the bottom.  To the left and right of the dock, I see the wallpaper.

I would actually *like* the app I'm in to extend all the way to the bottom of the monitor, with the dock on top of the bottom of the app.

So now it looks like this:

[image]

I'd like it to look like this (this is just a crude mockup, I don't really want to see the wallpaper bleeding through of course).  Can this be done?

[image]

Comment: Note that the tiny image of the girl is my smoking hot wife :)

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just turn dock hiding on? That way your app's window will use the full screen height and the dock will overlap when it is needed.

Comment: @MatthewLund Do you want apps to be non-dock-aware as a default?

Comment: My only concern with keeping the dock hidden is that several instant messaging programs jump around in the dock to let you know there's a message.  When the dock is hidden I see the jump for a second or two, then it's gone.  So if I'm looking away, I don't realize someone IM'd me.

Comment: @gentmatt - What does it mean for the apps to be non-dock-aware?

Comment: @MatthewLund The default behavior is that maximizing an application will not cover the dock ("dock-aware").

Comment: Then yes, if there's a way to make them non-dock-aware as a default, I'd like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you turn hiding on for the Dock, using the + button will extend maximized windows to the very bottom of the screen. When you mouse down near the bottom of the screen the dock will appear and be on top of any program windows on the display.

If you turn Dock hiding off after maximizing windows in this fashion they'll stay maximized all the way to the bottom of the screen. The Dock will be on top of the windows.

As promised, here's some AppleScript to make this happen:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set the autohide of the dock preferences to true
end tell
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    set frontApp to first application process whose frontmost is true
end tell
tell application (name of frontApp)
    set zoomed of window 1 to not (zoomed of window 1)
end tell
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    set the autohide of the dock preferences to false
end tell
```

You can [follow these directions](http://blog.fosketts.net/2010/08/09/assign-keyboard-shortcut-applescript-automator-service/) to assign that script to a keyboard short cut. I put the delays in there because I found every few runs the dock would unhide before the window had maximized and as such, it wouldn't be behind the dock.

Comment: That works.  Anyway to make this permanent so I don't need to continually repeat the steps?

Comment: Well, knowing the hide/restore shortcut helps at least.  opt-command-d.  So each time I want this consists of 3 steps.  opt-cmd-d, click the + icon on the app, opt-cmd-d.

Comment: Is there a shortcut to accomplish the same thing that clicking the + icon on the app does?

Comment: Wonder if I could do all 3 steps in an applescript and then assign a hot key to the applescript.  Then I'd be down to one keyboard shortcut :)

Comment: Yeah, there is no real setting to change this behavior. I've taken a look at [secrets.blacktree](http://secrets.blacktree.com/?showapp=com.apple.dock). Nothing there - but I'm not even sure if such a thing would be a dock setting.

Comment: @MatthewLund challenge accepted: I'll try and come up with some AppleScript for you that you can run as a service or assign to a hotkey.

Comment: Sweet, I look forward to it!

Comment: @MatthewLund AppleScript is there now.