# Full maximise (behind the dock)

Tags: keyboard, macos, dock, window-manager

## When "maximise" doesn't mean "maximise"

None of the maximise commands provide maximisation to fill the *whole screen*. When you have Dock not autohidden, then they only go up to the boundary of the dock. When you have Dock hidden they go *near* the edge of the screen but a few pixels short meaning **you can see other apps and the desktop behind them**.

### User error?

First I thought it was because I was using third party apps to maximise. I tested in Sizeup, Moom and BetterTouchTools. But it turns out **the native maximisation is broken to begin with**. *Nothing* will let a window automatically maximise to the full screen size, there will always be some pixels left over wherever the Dock is even if you have it hidden and at the smallest size setting.

### Non-solutions

At first I thought [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42742/i-would-like-my-application-to-overlap-the-dock-with-the-app-behind-of-course) was a duplicate and would provide my answer, but alas *it doesn't*. It is, of course, possible to move the window behind the dock protected pixels then resize it from the opposite side. But this has to be done for every window manually each time.

**Is there any way to make it so that maximise *fully* maximises across the *entire* screen?**

I really hope there is!

#### Bonus points

if anyone can find software that will allow keyboard shortcuts to do a different action moving a window dependant on where it currently is. e.g. in Windows 7 and above you can hit <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> over and over and the window will first maximise half left, then maximise half right on the display to the left of the current display, then to the left of that display and so on. Likewise, <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> will first restore a window, then minimise.

### Update

It's now been most of a year since I posted this question and despite extensive additional searching as well up updating to *El Capitan*, this OS X bug hasn't been fixed and I haven't been able to find any tool that offers a working solution. Any ideas at all?!

### Update 2

This has been marked as closed since a similar question has already got an answer - forgive, I can't see the link to this answer and have been unable to find it myself.

### Update 3

I've now been linked to the "answer" which says that it's not possible without disabling the Dock, Mission Control and the application switcher i.e. making crippling the core multitasking capabilities of the OS (and making it unusuable for me). I can say clearly that cutting off your nose to spite your face is not the sort of solution I was after. The "reason" given is not a) necessary as claimed by any reasoning I can come up with or b) relevant to required a border of clear pixels after maximising, c) true in any way as you can manually move windows behind the border and still have a fully-functioning Dock.

I don't understand why this is being marked as answered based on the other question since that's not really an answer even at a stretch - all the "answerer" says is they don't know of any reasonable solution.

Since it's possible manually, one would be inclined to believe it's technically possible. And there's no sound reason for "maximised" programs to behave in this way, again this is demontrabl

Comment: For the second part of the question, have you tried Spectacle? http://spectacleapp.com/

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that app doesn't do what I asked at all.

Comment: Is it really the case that you can't actually maximise windows on OS X?

Comment: I don't have a solution for your full-screen maximise, however since you mentioned Moom specifically: I use the same program with keyboard shortcuts assigned that allow me to move the front-most window to fill either the left or right portion of the screen (minus the pixels you discussed), or top or bottom of the screen. In addition, I have keyboard shortcuts for moving a window to the next available physical screen and previous screen.

Comment: Pretty sure these are all duplicates:
http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/211737/12285
http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/193274/12285
http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/141800/12285
http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/135647/12285
http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/148644/12285
http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/187001/12285
http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/96550/12285

Comment: Move the dock to the right or left side and auto hide. Then use full screen. Notice any difference?

Comment: @timothymh - thanks, I was unable to find those predating my question earlier. At least I know I'm not the only one it bugs!

Comment: @bjbk - should I? I currently use it on the right and the issue is still apparent.

Comment: With full screen apps, it doesn't show.  Maximizing the window (not the full screen) leaves pixels so as to trigger the dock.  I think I see your point.  Not really a bug, but allows for triggering the dock.  I use a black background mostly.  Do you notice a similar problem when hiding the Menu bar?

Comment: @bjbk - Except leaving the blank pixels there is not necessary to trigger the dock. I never use "full screen" apps as they are markedly less efficient for my workflow. Even using black pixels at that side of the desktop background is no use as windows overflowing the edge of the screen still show up beneath which is still distracting and ugly.

Comment: I have been using Macs since they were new, and I used a Lisa before that. Today (August 2020), I discovered that you can move the mouse to the corner of the window where it becomes a resizing arrow and option double click to fill the screen. More details: double click on any side to move that side to the edge of the screen, and add option to affect the opposite side as well.

Comment: @AndrewSwift that doesn't fix the issue this question is about.

Comment: Cmd-alt-D to hide the dock, alt-double-click window corner, cmd-alt-D to show the dock. For me, the window seems to go all the way to the edge, but it's a pretty clumsy shortcut.

Comment: Makes no difference at all. There's still a very obvious gap. The window doesn't change size as it can't move any further.

Comment: What system are you on?

Comment: El Capitan.....