# Is there a way to remove the gap between window edge and the screen edge when the Dock is hidden?

Tags: macos, dock

When you hide the Dock, OS X leaves a small gap at that edge. Is there a way to get rid of it?

In case you have never noticed the gap before here is a screenshot. Guess which side of the screen has the Dock:

[image]

Comment: El Capitan has not been released yet, it's still in beta. Betas can't be discussed here because it would require people to break their NDA to discuss it. The public beta may change things, but that's not available yet.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I got to remove the worlds El Capitan. The question is about the Dock.

Comment: I must have misunderstood. My bad. :p

Comment: Wait, so you mean that when a window is "zoomed", it doesn't zoom completely, and leaves a small border on the bottom, right?

Comment: Yes. Bottom or right/left. Depends where your Dock is located.

Comment: I had not noticed that before. Now it's going to bother me until I find a fix. Heh :p

Comment: It will bother you even more once the unnamed operating system will be released and you will be able to hide menu as well.

Comment: Ah, now I understand the point you made in your original post. Gotcha. That is troublesome.

Comment: I don't notice any gap, when the Dock is auto hiding. Using BetterSnapTool to make a window as big as the screen leaves a space on the bottom, but I can still resize the window to fill that space too, on OS X 10.10.

Comment: Screenshot plz?

Comment: Here you go @nicael.

Comment: Um, and where is the gap? the black line?

Comment: Yes the gap is the black line.

Comment: It's always done that, afaik. Old style Maximise leaves a few pixels of desktop showing at the bottom of the screen [my dock is in the default location]. Same if you drag a window size-handle to the bottom, it leaves a bit of space. You can fake it by moving the window to the edge, then resizing upwards, but I'm pretty sure after a relaunch, it will leave the gap again.

Comment: @kiamlaluno are you really doing it every time?? Since if you do, installing BetterSnapTool is kind of losing its purpose. You can just manually change all windows all the time, which is horrible experience (even with maximizing it with BST first)

Comment: I don't get it, OS X has otherwise so awesome UX, why there are absolutely ridiculous, I dare to say, rookie mistakes like this. top/bottom windows gaps, the inconsistency of maximizing windows (each app acts different, thats really terrible), switching windows when working with more windows of 1 app is huge pain too and don't let me start about another inconsistency when you close last window of some app, the app quits but another wont and you have useless bar on the top, which you are not aware of.

Comment: @Srneczek I don't get it. I simply said that with a tool that surely make a window as big as it can, I don't see any gaps, except on the bottom. I could do it by hand, but I could not be sure the window is taking the maximum size it can.

Comment: @kiamlaluno my point was that if you want to do it by hand, you have to do it all the time the window changes (even you move it by accident or you need to change the screen layout etc.) I did the same but it just beats the purpose of any resizing app when you have to adjust the size by hand after using the app shortcut.

Comment: @Srneczek Yes, but I did it this way to be sure to maximize the window as much as I could. I could have used other methods, but the point was not that. The point was saying _I am sure I maximized the window to its maximum size_.

Answer (score 2):

Not yet (as of macOS Sierra 10.12.6). When hiding the dock, the OS still leaves ~4 pixels of visible space presumably reserved for some part of the dock behavior. Third party window resizing doesn't seem to help either. Creator `fifafu` of BetterTouchTool [wrote](https://github.com/fifafu/BetterTouchTool/issues/454):

> You mean the gap when the dock is hidden? Unfortunately this is a
>   limitation given by the system :-(. I haven't found a way to
>   workaround that.

Note: This is more noticeable on lower resolution external displays (4px on a retina display is barely visible).

Some workarounds:

- Move the window over the visible pixels, then drag from the opposite side (but also notice the additional delay in showing the dock)
- Use an external display and set a different monitor as primary (drag the white menubar in the display arrangement in sys prefs), allowing full sizing on the non-primary display.

Related Apple SE but for visible docks: [Force windows to be maximized but not fullscreen?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252419/force-windows-to-be-maximized-but-not-fullscreen)

---

Have others noticed? Yes, lots. Macrumors dead ends:

https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/bottom-dead-space-with-automatic-hidden-dock.1716910/
https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/hiding-dock-still-leaves-a-few-pixels-unused.1208427/
https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-to-remove-space-between-window-and-dock.1094679/
https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/hidden-dock-small-space-in-the-bottom-of-the-screen.931858/

It's even caused bug reports for OS X app developers:

https://github.com/eczarny/spectacle/issues/555
https://github.com/fifafu/BetterTouchTool/issues/672
https://github.com/search?q=mac+dock+gap&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

---

I'll add that this issue exists vertically as well:

[image]

[image]

Manual workaround
[image]

Comment: You said, "_... the OS still leaves ~20 pixels of visible space presumably reserved for some part of the dock behavior_", well you obviously didn't actually measure how many pixels it left, as it's nowhere near ~20, more like ~4, however if you consider that perceived space is actually the shadow of the window, it's not really a space.

Comment: In case the first comment wasnt clear, If you take your second picture, the one with the red arrow pointing to what might be perceived as a space, and open it in an app like GIMP where you can magnify it and check color values... the perceived ~4 pixel space is actually the shadow of the window and as such is IMO technically not a space since a shadow is a part of displaying the window.

Comment: I can see how the gap is irksome - whether 4 or 20 pixels. This is absolutely a common complaint - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211737/full-height-window-is-not-full-height-el-capitan

Comment: Also, I’ve edited comments slightly - be sure to assume the dialog is friendly and meant to help or illuminate this answer as opposed to refuting it. +1 answer in my book

Comment: @user3439894 with two or more displays, the displays without the dock do not have the gap. Only the display with the dock has the gap. Thus the desktop UI is inconsistent regardless of shadows. 

The dimensions of the gap are not really relevant to the discussion, but good catch. I did measure the dimensions but accidentally took the width of my drag instead of the height. The answer has been updated.