# Is it possible to remove the gap between the menu and an app's title bar?

Tags: menu-bar

Similar to [the gap between a maxmized window and the edge of the screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193274/is-the-a-way-to-remove-the-gap-between-window-edge-and-the-screen-edge-when-the), there is a gap between the title bar of a maxmized window and the menu bar.

I have a full-screen iTerm window in the background, with "use Lion-style Fullscreen windows" disabled.  When content in the iterm window changes, it's visible in this gap and also the also it makes the title bar of the foreground window flash.

Is it possible to remove the gap between title bar and menu bar?

Comment: have you got a pic? I can't see any gap, single-pixel black line for me, which I can't push anything closer than, even manually.

Comment: I have a full-screen iTerm window in the background, with "use Lion-style Fullscreen windows" disabled.  So a bit of an edge-case I guess - sorry for not mentioning in the question.

Comment: @IconDaemon done