# Full height window is not full height El Capitan

Tags: macos, window-manager

I have the issue that my windows are not really full height in OS X. I'm new to OS X so I don't know if this is new.

Here is an example image:

[image: few pixels at the bottom of the window]

Watch the few bottom pixels, the background just shows there, because the window ends. This is obviously not the full screen mode for windows like in a separate space but this is the maximize with the option key.

I am on an Early 2013 MacBook Pro Retina if that is relevant. I'm using the smallest scaling so 1650x1050

Edit: Changing the scaling didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gap at the bottom of the window happens when your Dock is placed at the bottom of the screen and hidden. If it is visible, there is no gap, and if the Dock is placed to the side of the screen, the gap appears on that side when it is hidden.

I'm not aware of any way to disable this behavior, but it has been present in OS X for some time.

If you are looking for maximum window size, you could try Full Screen mode, which fills the entire screen with the contents of the window, and even hides the menu and title bars.

Comment: That would leave the gap on the left/right side D: I dislike fullscreen mode since I can't stack windows on another but I guess its what I have to go with.

Comment: @danielps1 Yeah, I'm not a fan of the gap either. Though, if you weren't already aware, El Capitan offers a split-screen full-screen mode, so you can now have two apps in full-screen mode at once!

Answer (score 3):

Apple designs the screens to leave a gap between the top window and the menu bar (especially noticeable with a dark menu bar and a bright background image) and also maintains a gap between the physical bottom of the screen and the window.

If I were to guess, it's to preserve shadows and "depth" of the interface and they made a conscious decision to implement windowing this way.

You might have to file some bug reports and gather use cases for how this is bad to get them to reverse this decision. It's hard to unsee once you notice it, but I don't think it's just a bug in their code.